# Need help understanding a proof of the remainder theorem

Tags: polynomials

Proof.
$p(x) = (x-a)q(x) + r(x)$
Rearranging, $r(x) = p(x) - (x-a)q(x)$
Plug $x=a$, $r(a) = p(a) - (a-a)q(x)$
$r(a) = p(a)$

To me this seems like it only proves that $r(a) = p(a)$ for the specific instance where $x=a$. The textbook that I am using also states that this is true. It states that a proof will have to include the fact that $r(a)$ is a constant as $(x-a)$ is a first degree polynomial, and therefore, the remainder will always equal to $p(a)$. This makes sense to me, however, it still seems like it only applies for the specific instance where $x=a$, and does not prove the theorem.

Any explanation will be much appreciated. For reference I was using an A-level textbook.

Comment: $r(a)$ and $p(a)$ are constants, they are not dependent on $x$.

Comment: @lulu I don't see how that addresses OP's question. I actually agree with OP here. All the proof in the question does is show that $r(a)=p(a),$ which is kind of obvious, and doesn't prove that $p(x)=(x-a)q(x) + p(a).$ For example, the "proof" in the question does not explain why we cannot have $p(x) = x^2 = 2(x-a) +r(x)\ $(so here $q(x)=2)).$ The conclusion of the proof in the question is that $p(a)=r(a),$ which is true, but we still don't know what $r(x)$ is, sothe remainder theorem has not been proved...

Comment: If however, we *assume* from the outset that $r(x)$ is a constant, then the remainder theorem has been proved. Either OP has not put the entire proof from the book in the body of the question, or the book's proof lacks details.

Comment: Also, it doesn't surprise me this comes from an A-Level textbook. They always use hand-wavy proofs and lack details.

Comment: @AdamRubinson  I took the question as asking just about the proof that $r(a)=p(a)$, the argument appears to assume the remainder theorem at the start...it certainly isn't a proof of that result.  Of course I might have misunderstood...the OP should clarify.

Comment: Well based on the title and OP's question, I think he was expecting a proof of the remainder theorem.

Comment: Hi @lulu, sorry if the question was unclear, but basically the author was using r(a)=p(a) as a proof of the theorem, their exact line was, "Since the divisor (x − a) is a 1st-degree polynomial, r(x) must be a 0th-degree polynomial, i.e. a constant. We showed above that the remainder is sometimes (i.e. at least once) equal to p(a). So, being a constant, it is always equal to p(a).". This did not make sense to me, hence my question.

Comment: Are you looking for a proof that $r(x)$ is a constant or $0$th-degree polynomial, which is outside the quoted proof?

Comment: As stated,  there is no reason for $r(x)$ to be constant.  You could have anything at all for $q(x)$, and then define $r(x)$ as $p(x)-(x-a)q(x)$.  But you will always have $p(a)=r(a)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's start with the theorem and its proof.

The remainder theorem states, if you divide a polynomial $P(x)$ by $x−a$, the remainder would be P(a).

And here's the proof.

**Step 1.** And polynomial P(x) can be written as

$$P(x) = (x-a) \cdot q(x) + r$$

Here $r$ is a constant. Because the remainder will be of a degree smaller than the degree of the divisor. And the divisor, $x - a$, is of degree 1.

**Step 2.** Substituting $a$ in place of $x$, we get

$$\begin{align*}
P(a) &= (a - a) \cdot q(x) + r \\[0.3cm]
&= 0 \cdot q(x) + r \\[0.3cm]
&= r
\end{align*}$$

Now, it's important to understand that just because we used $x = a$ in this step, doesn't mean the value of r depends on $a$. Remember $r$ is a constant. Our substitution is just a trick to get rid of the other term by making it $0$.

Step 2 is simply where we do the calculation. The value of $r$ is fixed in step 1, where we used $x - a$ as the divisor. And that's something in the very statement of the theorem.

So again, as long as the divisor is $x - a$, the remainder would be $P(a)$.